# Can you give priority to a scss partial?

Tags: css, sass

I'm doing media queries in a seperate scss file named _media.scss, so I can seperate my main style.scss file from the media queries to make things easier to manage.

However it seems that because i import the _media.scss file at the top of the style.scss file then because of the nature of the cascading rules, the style.scss rules are overriding the _media rules as they come after the import.

To get the _media rules to take priority i'm having to add on !important to a lot of rules. I tried cutting and pasting all the media queries to the bottom of the style.scss file and it works without the !important flag.

Is there any way to give the _media partial priority over the style file so I fix this?

Code:
Inside the style.scss file:

```
@import 'config';
@import 'utilities';
@import 'form';
@import 'dropdown';
@import 'animations';
@import 'media';

.logo {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

Inside the _media.scss:

```
@media(max-width: 500px) {
.logo {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
}
```

Inside the chrome dev tools, i've got the same classes as above with font-size: 1.5em crossed out.

Not sure why 2em is taking priority?

Comment: put the scss file _media in the bottom of the list of imported files

Comment: Just a reminder try to avoid !important in your CSS.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid !important but I can't figure out why the media queries won't override the standard rules..

Comment: @Jabberwocky I have

Comment: @NickVanLoocke just something as simple as font size won't override.

Comment: @PaulB Then it's not a matter of where you put the partial. It's about specifications. If for example you have a min-width and a max width under the same class usually the max-width is stronger (from my experience) and causes problems. Check if that's something you should be looking into

Comment: @Jabberwocky yeah I understand but I can't even get the font-size to change at the moment. I've a logo in the nav that just has a class of .logo. The font-size is set to 2em. With a media query for smartphones set as max-width of 500px, I'm having to use the important flag just to get a font-size of 1.5em to take priority. There are no other rules in that class.

Comment: @Pete no problem.

Comment: Ok, you import the media before the initial .logo - you need to move the import to the end of your styles.scss (or have an index as your entry point and then just import your styles.scss before your media.scss)

Comment: @Pete Aha cheers! That's what I was looking for. I assumed that you had to have import statements at the top of the file, hence the confusion. I didn't realise you could import the partial at any point in the file.

Comment: I think you can import them anywhere - people just put them at the top so you can easily see what is being imported (hence the suggestion for change of entry point so you can see all imports together)

Comment: @Pete I've totally sorted it now, it works with all !important flags removed. Thanks for your help!